# Is there any security framework for lift + mongodb

Tags: mongodb, lift

Is there any recommended security framework for lift framework and supports mongodb as the backend, possibly using rogue out there? Out of the box lift supports RDBMS. I am looking for the possibility to use lift with mongodb, but wondering whether there is already a security fraemework for lift + mongodb out there.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Lift-Shiro integration that Timothy Perrett cooked up? Seems that would fit the bill, or you could adapt it to a different security framework if you don't want to use Shiro.

http://blog.getintheloop.eu/2011/08/23/using-apache-shiro-with-lift/

If you want more thorough answers, you may want to consider asking on the Lift mailing list - http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb. That is the official support community and sees more Lift activity and questions than Stackoverflow